# Java reading Icy stream seems to omit a lot of data at the beginning

Tags: java, shoutcast

When I'm trying to read an Icy stream in Java, a lot of mp3 data seems to be omitted at the beginning because the first metadata block is coming too early. Here is my code:

```
    sock = new Socket(url.getHost(), (url.getPort() == -1 ? 80 : url.getPort()));
    OutputStream out = sock.getOutputStream();
    String req = "GET " + (url.getPath().equals("") ? "/" : url.getPath()) + " HTTP/1.0\r\nIcy-MetaData: 1\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n";
    out.write(req.getBytes());
    BufferedInputStream buffer = new BufferedInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
    BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(buffer));
    String line = "";
    String beginning = "";
    while(!beginning.equals("icy-metaint:")) {
        line = read.readLine();
        try {
            beginning = line.substring(0, 12);
        } catch (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException exc) {
        }
    }
    String metaintstr = line.substring(12);
    metaint = Integer.valueOf(metaintstr);
    while (!line.equals("")) {
        line = read.readLine();
    }
    in = new MetadataInputStream(buffer, metaint);
```

My MetadataInputStream code is as follows:

```
public class MetadataInputStream extends InputStream {
private InputStream in;
private int count;
private int metaint;
private String meta;
private MetadataChangeListener listen;

public MetadataInputStream(InputStream iin, int mmetaint) {
    in = iin;
    metaint = mmetaint;
    count = 0;
}

public int read() throws IOException {
    if (count == metaint) {
        count = 0;
        int length = in.read() * 16;
        System.err.println(length);
        byte[] info = new byte[length];
        in.read(info, 0, length);
        meta = new String(info);
        if (listen != null) {
            listen.metadataChanged(meta);
        }
    }
    count++;
    int res = in.read();
    return res;
}

public String getMetaData() {
    return meta;
}

public void addMetadataListener(MetadataChangeListener llisten) {
    listen = llisten;
}
```

}

But, which is the most "amazing" thing, playing the stream works fine! What is going on here?

Comment: When you say "a lot of data" is missing... might it by any chance be the amount of data the `BufferedReader` has buffered while reading a line at a time? It's generally a bad idea to wrap an input stream in something like an `InputStreamReader` and then *also* read from the input stream directly.

Comment: Thank you very much! The problem was really that the data buffered got lost. Now I changed my MetadataInputStream code such that it uses a Reader instead of the InputStream and passed the BufferedReader as the argument.

Comment: Oh no, but now the stream doesn't play any more...